# Jenkins cannot update composer due to bad environment settings

Tags: php, jenkins, composer-php

Console log:

```
+ COMPOSER_HOME=/home/jenkins/composer
+ HOME=/home/jenkins
+ php composer.phar install
         [RuntimeException]                                                                        
  The HOME or COMPOSER_HOME environment variable must be set for composer to run correctly
```

This used to work, now it's giving me this error. I am even setting these vars explicitly now, but it still fails. What happened to Jenkins to cause this failure? How do I fix it? I have tried a couple things I've found here on SO but none have helped.

Answer (score 1):

There is an error with the latest version of composer.
First, update to this alpha version using this command:

`export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update 1.0.0-alpha11`

More info [here](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/4789)